# I can't be root

Tags: linux, sudo, root, opensuse, mode

My school gave me a dump with different partition, I have to Work on the linux one, it's a open suse modified by the school.. sometimes I need to be root for install stuff with zypper example, they don't want to tell us how to be root, I look everywhere I can on Internet but I still dont know how to do.

I can be root for only one session, I have to press "e" then put init=/bin/sh at the end of the "linux = "  in the starting option I think to start a single user mode prompt, then make passwd then passwd root, then vi /etc/sudoers, add ## at the beginning of 2 lines then reboot, launch my session make sudo su, and it's ask me my_username's password.

If I don't do all the stuff before it ask me root's password... I tried evreything to swith me in the groups of root but it didn't change anything

Comment: "they don't want to tell us how to be root" We are not going to tell you how to break restrictions on a computer owned by someone else. Ask your IT administrator.

Comment: oh no I am the owner of the computer, in my school they make us buy the computer the beginning of the year, we all have the same in my promotion, they just give us a dump, a linux partition and a windows one.

Comment: it's my computer, there is only dump the gave us that have been modified, and we have to found how to be root but i tried everything and it's still not working

Comment: So it's an assignment to find out how to root the partition?

Comment: they want from us to find how to be root, it's a computer school.. ;) (sorry for my english)

Comment: Then you should do it yourself. Otherwise it is cheating.

Comment: it's been since the beginning of the year i tried .. 3 months

Comment: Just pretend you forgot the root password, then Google it.